# How to deal with xapian php exceptions

Tags: php, exception, xapian

Help with using the xapian php wrapper.

I have a couple of custom exception handlers for different categories of errors (I'm thinking of seperating them out more).
Xapian handles errors by throwing standard Exception objects. 
I would like to use a custom exception handler for these though. How do I go about using a custom exception for a standard Exception that has already been thrown? Or any other ideas, perhaps how to get Xapian to throw some other exception type?

Answer (score 1):

the kludgy way: wrap every xapian API call in try..catch blocks, and throw more specific custom exceptions in the catch clause.

or the hackish way: modify the source of the xapian php extension (which i assume is written in C?) to throw custom exceptions (that you would also have to define in the extension source)

Answer (score 0):

Catch the generic exceptions from Xapian, figure out what they are, then throw more specific expections.

Or...if you'd like Xapian to behave differently than it currently does, well, it *is* an open source project. You know what to do. :)